# Regular Expression to match string starting with dynamic string

Tags: regex, angular, devexpress

I am using Angular devexpress simple items and i am trying to show a specific login user in a  
the specific login that should start with the user name then a '-' then another string
well i tried this solution but i steel have a problem when the login have charchter like a , it will be masked. i want a rule that don't mask the login user 
this picture describe what i am trying to do
[image]

this is my code below

```
                       <dxi-item dataField="login" [editorOptions]="{ mask: loginUser +'-XXXX', maskRules: rules }">
```

and

```
    this.rules = { 'X': /[a-z]/ };
    this.loginUser = localStorage.getItem("login");
```

any help please

Answer (score -1):

```
let str = 'Mustafa Omran;',
search = 'Omran',
isInString = !(str.indexOf(search) == -1);
```

> more details see Mozilla Docs [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: And how this could help me !?

Comment: @IlyesAtoui you need to search in dynamic string